# Remove search box with bFilter still set to True in DataTable

Tags: datatables

I need to apply custom filtering function in my datatable. For this, I need to set `"bFilter": true`. But I don't need search box. How can I do that?

```js
var holiday_filter = $('#holiday_table').DataTable({
   "bPaginate": false,
   "bLengthChange": false,
   "bFilter": true,
   "bSort": false,
   "bInfo": false,
   "order": [[0, 'desc']],
   //"aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 20, 30],
   'iDisplayLength': 4,
   "bAutoWidth": false
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option (default value `lfrtip`) without `f` which represents filtering input.

For example:

```js
var holiday_filter = $('#holiday_table').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
   'dom': 'lrtip'
});
```